# Retrieve Prismic slices content in Nuxtjs using GraphQL not working in project

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js

When testing the query in the browser I can easily query slices but once in my project, when I try to query Prismic slices it all falls apart.
Packages: apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory, apollo-link-prismic

the query looks something like:

```
{
  thepage(uid: "page", lang: "en-gb") {
    page_title
    page_description
    body {
      ... on ThePageBodyHero {
        type
        fields {
          title
          description
          button_text
          button_link {
            _linkType
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this works in the interface but as soon as I add the slices section in the project the query returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

When using Apollo Client with Slices, you need to have a proper cache setup to resolve the slices. Meaning having a fragment matcher setup based on the introspection query to Prismic: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments#fragment-matcher.
We planned to do it in the Prismic library for Apollo so people won't have to care about it no more.
In your case you got a 404 but it would be interesting to see who return a 404 because all the symptoms seem to lead to what I just explained.
Tell me if you got more info on your side ;)

In the meantime, here is a proper implementation: https://github.com/birkir/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql/src/utils/getApolloClient.ts#L17